# Iterate through loop and add variables together

Tags: php, while-loop, accumulate

I have the following loop which shows the fields money and percent. I want to add all the money together as it iterates through, how can I do this and echo out a total outside the loop?

```
while(the_repeater_field('income')) {
   the_sub_field('money');
   the_sub_field('percent');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$Sum_Money   = 0;
$Sum_Percent = 0;

while (the_repeater_field('income')) {
  $Money   = the_sub_field('money'); 
  $Percent = the_sub_field('percent');
  $Sum_Money   += $Money;
  $Sum_Percent += $Percent;
}

echo $Sum_Money;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to reflect the new format of the question. Here is the answer:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$totalPercent = 0;
while(the_repeater_field('income')) {
    $total += the_sub_field('money');
    $totalPercent += the_sub_field('percent');
}
echo "Total: $total, Percent: $totalPercent";
?>
```